# how to replace default woocomerce star raiting icon with fontawesome?

Tags: css, wordpress, icons, font-awesome

I am trying to change default woocommerce star raiting icon with a font-awesome icon

but fontawesome code is plaicing the wrong icon instead of what I need

[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnxKF.png)

I am trying to replace stars with filled circles but the icon I get is an empty circle.

Could be a matter of fontawesome version?
Any idea how to figure this out?

Because the css content code that I find for the filled icon that I need is actually the one I am using in my css clases to replace the stars icons:

```
.woocommerce .star-rating:before{
    font-family: 'FontAwesome' !important; 
    content: '\f111\f111\f111\f111\f111' !important;
    color: #d5d5d5 !important;
}

.woocommerce .star-rating span:before{
    font-family: 'FontAwesome' !important; 
    content: '\f111\f111\f111\f111\f111' !important;
    color: #FF9800 !important;
}
```

But all I get is empty circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using the wrong codes.

```css
.woocommerce .star-rating:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome' !important;
  content: '\f10c\f10c\f10c\f10c\f10c' !important;
  color: #d5d5d5 !important;
}

.woocommerce .star-rating span:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome' !important;
  content: '\f111\f111\f111\f111\f111' !important;
  color: #FF9800 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="woocommerce">
  <div class="star-rating"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is the other way around, I need to show filled circles, not stars

Comment: yeah that's actually what I need, but for some reason that same code that works here, in my products slider shows empty circles instead of filled circles just as your code snippet.  (See the image attached in mi question to see what I get using this snippet you shared)

Comment: oh it is ready! I realized I was targeting two fontawesome libraries, delete one and keep the one you share and it worked, thank you so much